# Using pivot sql join 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, pivot, pivot-table

master
I have 3 tables:

1. tb_siswa
2. tb_spp
3. tb_bulan

Here are the contents of the three tables above:

1. tb_siswa

[image]

2. tb_spp

[image]

3. tb_bulan

[image]

I want to show my sql like the view below, using sql pivot

[image]

I hope  someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table on related keys and then use conditional aggregation to pivot the result:

```
select s.nis,
    s.nm_lengkap,
    sum(case when b.nm_bulan = 'Januari' then p.nominal else 0 end) as Januari,
    sum(case when b.nm_bulan = 'Februari' then p.nominal else 0 end) as Februari,
    sum(case when b.nm_bulan = 'Maret' then p.nominal else 0 end) as Maret,
    ...
from tb_siswa s
join tb_spp p on s.id = p.id_siswa
join tb_bulan b on p.id_bulan = b.id
group by s.nis,
    s.nm_lengkap;
```